# How to get numpy sub-array view when array ndim is not known until runtime?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a Python numpy N-dimensional array with shape `M x N x ... x T`, but I do not know the number of dimensions (rank) of the array until runtime.

How can I create a view of a sub-array of that array, specified by two vectors with length rank: `extent` and `offset`?
    import numpy as np

```
def select_subrange( orig_array, subrange_extent_vector, subrange_offset_vector ):
    """
    returns a view of orig_array offset by the entries in subrange_offset_vector
    and with extent specified by entries in subrange_extent_vector.
    """
    # ??? 
    return subarray
```

I'm stuck because the slicing examples I have found require `[ start:end, ... ]` entries for each array dimension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you right, use

```
orig_array[[slice(o, o+e) for o, e in zip(offset, extent)]]
```

Example:

```
>>> x = np.arange(4**4).reshape((4, 4, 4, 4))
>>> x[0:2, 1:2, 2:3, 1:3]
array([[[[25, 26]]],


       [[[89, 90]]]])
>>> offset = (0, 1, 2, 1)
>>> extent = (2, 1, 1, 2)
>>> x[[slice(o, o+e) for o, e in zip(offset, extent)]]
array([[[[25, 26]]],


       [[[89, 90]]]])
```

Comment: Yes! You have my intent correct. The code looks to be working for me. So `slice` is new, but I gather that represents the `a:b` notation?

Comment: @NoahR: Yes, see [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#slice).